# Node Application in firebase cannot connect to web3 RPC

Tags: node.js, firebase, web3js

When I run the below piece of code using node, it is able to connect to external server. But when I deploy this code on firebase, it fails.

```
const Web3      = require('web3');
var web3        = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://<my-server-ip>:8545"));
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express   = require('express');

if(web3.isConnected()) {
    console.log("Success")

} else {

   console.log("Failure")

}
const app       = express();
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I verified following things to troubleshoot this problem:

- The rpc server is accessible globally from anywhere
- The web3 version written in package.json is `"web3": "^0.18.4"`

Answer (score 0):

If there are more logs from Firebase, it would be helpful to attach them to the original question as well. For the purpose of this answer, I'm assuming that it just prints `Failure` to the console.

To troubleshoot, do the following:

- Check logs of your Ethereum node at `<my-server-ip>` and see if there are some additional errors there, or if there were connection attempts at all from Firebase IP.
- If you see no connection attempts in the Ethereum node logs, then even though you mentioned it's accessible I'd suggest to double-check its firewall/network settings to make sure it allows connections from Firebase.